# Unblocked Browser

Tags: web-browser, web

I'm looking for a way to run a web browser like Firefox on my Windows 10 computer. The administrator has restricted running .exe files (except those in %appdata% and preinstalled programs, like Outlook and Word). However, I do have java on my computer. There are two ways to proceed:

```
1. Run a browser using java
2. Find a way to run .exe files
```

Do you have any software recommendations for either of these?

Comment: [Mozilla Firefox Portable Edition](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable), which runs as a standalone app without needing to be installed, may be what you're looking for. In addition to Firefox there are more than 300 other portable apps at the same website.

Comment: @karel Unfortunately, PortableApps.com is an exe file, so I cannot run it.

Comment: Try downloading a tiny .exe file from PortableApps.com to test whether .exe files are hard blocked by the administrator. [winMd5Sum Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/winmd5sum_portable) is only 294 Kb.

Comment: @karel that appears to be blocked as well. I guess .exe files are hard blocked by the admin

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits. You could start with [SuperUser](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example.

Comment: What about any portable browser copied into AppData? Pretty much any software ultimately comes with an .exe file as its main entry point. Except if you find a browser developed in an interpreted language and you happen to have the right interpreter allowed in your system.

Comment: For some reason, I can't edit existing exe files in AppData and run them. However, I can run the existing exe files in AppData. I believe there is a registry of applications that I am allowed to execute or something like that. [Gngr.jar](https://gngr.info/) works fine for now, since it is written in Java.

Comment: Trivial task to use AppLocker to only allow whitelisted applications to run.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the admin to install firefox. Typically admins are quite friendly folk. Be aware that skirting rules by finding ways to run exe files will likely draw the ire of the admin and if they discover it, they will be less likely to install firefox for you than if you asked up-front.

Other than that, you could try a java-based web browser [such as Lobo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xamj/files/Lobo%20Browser/0.98.4/) which is a ".jar" file.

Failing that, you could perform the requests manually using telnet from cmd. (And get uber nerd-points). But that's not really a browser.